# Why I'm not able to navigate to source code of DLL from Module in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to debug my Xamarin forms project using the **pdb files**. I have loaded my symbols and when I **double click on the DLL in module** it doesn't take me to **source code**. As you can see the following screenshot.
[image]

Even though the symbols are loaded the path of symbol file is   **C:\Workspace\Xamarin.BaseLibrary\Output\netstandard2.1\BaseLibrary.MobileClient.dll.mdb**
I'm not sure if this is proper. I have tried solutions like making the debug type to **portable** as well as **full**. Also in in the debug settings I have disabled **enable just my code**. I don't know what I am missing. Any suggetions?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 supports Source Link for the `.NET debugger` but does not currently support Source Link for the `Mono debugger`. Therefore, you can use Source Link to debug `UWP` apps, but not `Android` or `iOS` app.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT So how can I do debugging in Android and iOS then? Is it possible to do source linking in iOS and android? If It's not can u suggest me some valid documentation for that.

Comment: For now, we can not do that with Android or iOS app.